# Test explorer not running all tests using xunit framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xunit, visual-studio-test-runner

I am using X unit framework in .NET test project and suddenly the test explorer stopped running all tests, but just a part of them(literally did nothing different for it to stop working).

I tried to clean, rebuild solution and update nugget packages, but it's still doing the same thing - every time different number of tests stay not run.

Recently updated to VS 2022 and had no issue till now.

This is the proj file -

```
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NBuilder" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
```

Can you please advice what I can try to sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking out an earlier version of the repository and running the tests?

Comment: I get this all the time.   Look in the Output panel, change the "Show Output from" to Tests, and you'll probably see loads of exceptions.  I don't know what the problem is, but I got something very similar this morning., rebooted, and it's now working.

Comment: @Neil It worked, I had an issue with code, but the built was successful so I couldn't identify the problem. Thanks a lot!